# Large Search Box in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I am using http://bootswatch.com/united/ theme and I need a `large search box` center aligned with my logo above it same as Google.com on my index page.

The only search code which I could get is this:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
  <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

But there is no search button attached which could be attached using this large button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large button</button>
```

How do I align it properly?

Comment: Check out [Bootstrap docs, input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups), scroll to Button addons.

Comment: In components I could not find anything related to large search box. There is only nav bar search box which is aligned to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to put the button inside the form and after input type=text (don´t leave gaps between them).

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" placeholder="Search"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large button</button>
    </form>
```

Then you can play with the css, usually the elements get display: inline-block; and center the form with margin: 0 auto;

Comment: I am new to bootstrap. Can you share some websites or resources. I could not align it to the middle.

Comment: OK. I did managed to get it aligned and everything but now the problem is that the size of search input box is not increasing. Can you help me with it.

here is the code I am using:

<form class="form-search">
  <div class="input-append">
     <input type="text" class="search-query btn-large" placeholder="Type here..." style="padding: 11px 19px;font-size: 17.5px;">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large">
          <i class="icon-search"></i>
          Search
      </button>
   </div>
</form>

Comment: What you mean not increasing? Put a example on the jsfiddle with all markups and css